# jq - add objects from file into json array

Tags: array, json, jq

I want to add an array with elements and value into an existing json file using jq.

I already have a file (input.json) with

```
{
  "id": 9,
  "version": 0,
  "lastUpdTs": 1532371267968,
  "name": "Training"
}
```

I want to add this into another groups array into this json (orig.json)

```
[
  {
    "name": "JAYS",
    "sourceConnection": {
      "name": "ORACLE_connection",
      "connectionType": "JDBC",
      "commProtocol": "JDBC"
    },
    "checked": true,
    "newlyAdded": false,
    "id": null,
    "groups": [],
    "displayName": "SCOTT",
    "defaultLevel": "MANAGED"
  }
]
```

The end result should look like

```
[
  {
    "name": "JAYS",
    "sourceConnection": {
      "name": "ORACLE_connection",
      "connectionType": "JDBC",
      "commProtocol": "JDBC"
    },
    "checked": true,
    "newlyAdded": false,
    "id": null,
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "version": 0,
        "lastUpdTs": 1532371267968,
        "name": "Training"
      }
    ],
    "displayName": "SCOTT",
    "defaultLevel": "MANAGED"
  }
]
```

I know how to add elements into an array, but not sure how to pass in from a file.

```
jq '.[].groups += [{"INPUT": "HERE"}]' ./orig.json
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`jq` has a flag for feeding actual JSON contents with its `--argjson` flag. What you need to do is, store the content of the first JSON file in a variable in `jq`'s context and update it in the second JSON

```
jq --argjson groupInfo "$(<input.json)" '.[].groups += [$groupInfo]' orig.json
```

The part `"$(<input.json)"` is shell re-direction construct to output the contents of the file given and with the argument to `--argjson` it is stored in the variable `groupInfo`. Now you add it to the `groups` array in the actual filter part.

Putting it in another way, the above solution is equivalent of doing this

```
jq --argjson groupInfo '{"id": 9,"version": 0,"lastUpdTs": 1532371267968,"name": "Training" }' \
   '.[].groups += [$groupInfo]' orig.json
```

Comment: Noting that `$(<file)` is a ksh/bash/zsh extension and not otherwise portable, however. You could use `cat` instead.

Answer (score 14):

This is the exact case that [the `input` function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#input) is for:

> `input` and inputs [...] read from the same sources (e.g., stdin, files named on the command-line) as jq itself. These two builtins, and jq’s own reading actions, can be interleaved with each other.

That is, `jq` reads an object/value in from the file and executes the pipeline on it, and anywhere `input` appears the *next* input is read in and is used as the result of the function.

That means you can do:

```
jq '.[].groups += [input]' orig.json input.json
```

with exactly the command you've written already, plus `input` as the value. The `input` expression will evaluate to the (first) object read from the next file in the argument list, in this case the entire contents of `input.json`.

If you have *multiple* items to insert you can use `inputs` instead with the same meaning. It will apply across a single or multiple files from the command line equally, and `[inputs]` represents all the file bodies as an array.

It's also possible to interleave things to process multiple `orig` files, each with one companion file inserted, but separating the outputs would be a hassle.

Comment: But this probably doesn't let me incorporate non-json files. With `--arg` I can do: `jq --arg "$(<1.txt)" '{file: $file}'`.

Comment: Also, the file might not be on disk. You might have retrieved the file from the internet to a variable (`file=$(curl ...)`). In which case, there's probably no way to use `input` function. `<(echo "$file")` doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelHomer how if we want to do changes in input.json before merging?

Answer (score 3):

New versions of `jq` support `slurpfile`

This achieves the result you are looking for: `jq '.[].groups += $inputs' orig.json --slurpfile inputs input.json`

Tested in jq 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Use dot as placeholder

```
echo '{
  "id": 9,
  "version": 0,
  "lastUpdTs": 1532371267968,
  "name": "Training"
}' | jq '[
  {
    "name": "JAYS",
    "sourceConnection": {
      "name": "ORACLE_connection",
      "connectionType": "JDBC",
      "commProtocol": "JDBC"
    },
    "checked": true,
    "newlyAdded": false,
    "id": null,
    "groups": [.],
    "displayName": "SCOTT",
    "defaultLevel": "MANAGED"
  }
]'
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "JAYS",
    "sourceConnection": {
      "name": "ORACLE_connection",
      "connectionType": "JDBC",
      "commProtocol": "JDBC"
    },
    "checked": true,
    "newlyAdded": false,
    "id": null,
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "version": 0,
        "lastUpdTs": 1532371267968,
        "name": "Training"
      }
    ],
    "displayName": "SCOTT",
    "defaultLevel": "MANAGED"
  }
]
```

```
jq --version
jq-1.6
```