# Add JSON objects to array using jq

Tags: bash, scripting, json, jq

My goal is to output a JSON object using `jq` on the output of a `find` command in bash. It could either be a one-line command or a bash script.

I have this command which creates JSON objects from each line of output:

```
find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -name "D*" | \
while read line; \
do jq -n \
--arg name "$(basename "$line")" \
--arg path "$line" \
'{name: $name, path: $path}'; \
done
```

The output looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Desktop",
  "path": "/Users/username/Desktop"
}
{
  "name": "Documents",
  "path": "/Users/username/Documents"
}
{
  "name": "Downloads",
  "path": "/Users/username/Downloads"
}
```

But I need these objects to be in an array, and I need the array to be the value of a a parent object's single key called `items`, like so:

```
{"items": [
    {
      "name": "Desktop",
      "path": "/Users/username/Desktop"
    },
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "path": "/Users/username/Documents"
    },
    {
      "name": "Downloads",
      "path": "/Users/username/Downloads"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried adding the square brackets to the `jq` output string for each line (`'[{name: $name, path: $path}]';`) and that adds the brackets but not the commas between the array elements.

I found possible solutions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460985/jq-add-objects-from-file-into-json-array) but I could not figure out how to use them while looping through each line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This trick with the `jq 1.5` `inputs` streaming filter seems to do it

```
... | jq -n '.items |= [inputs]'
```

Ex.

```
$ find ~/ -maxdepth 1 -name "D*" | 
    while read line; do 
      jq -n --arg name "$(basename "$line")" \
            --arg path "$line" \
        '{name: $name, path: $path}'
    done | jq -n '.items |= [inputs]'
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Downloads",
      "path": "/home/steeldriver/Downloads"
    },
    {
      "name": "Desktop",
      "path": "/home/steeldriver/Desktop"
    },
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "path": "/home/steeldriver/Documents"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Also, when seeing your example output I realized that I'd made a mistake in the example output that I included... it showed an invalid list of arrays for the value of the `items` field. I corrected the question just now. Your example produces a single array of objects, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `jq` directly from `find`, and then collecting the resulting data with `jq` to construct the final output, without any shell loops:

```bsh
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -name '[[:upper:]]*' \
    -exec jq -n --arg path {} '{ name: ($path|sub(".*/"; "")), path: $path }' \; |
jq -n -s '{ items: inputs }'
```

The `jq` that is being executed via `-exec` creates a JSON object per found pathname.  It strips off everything in the pathname up to the last slash for the `name` value, and uses the pathname as is for the `path` value.

The final `jq` reads the data from `find` into an array with `-s`, and simply inserts it as the `items` array in a new JSON object.  The final `jq` invocation could also be written `jq -n '{ items: [inputs] }`.

Example result (note that I was using `[[:upper:]*` in place of `D*` for the `-name` pattern with `find`):

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "path": "/home/myself/Documents"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mail",
      "path": "/home/myself/Mail"
    },
    {
      "name": "Work",
      "path": "/home/myself/Work"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you dont mind using a programming language, this is pretty simple. Here is an
example with PHP:

```
<?php
$m1 = [
   'items' => []
];
$a1 = glob('~/D*');
foreach ($a1 as $s1) {
   $m1['items'][] = [
      'name' => basename($s1),
      'path' => $s1
   ];
}
echo json_encode($m1, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```